# Merge [symfony-recipe] into [symfony-flex]

Tags: support, synonym-request

[symfony-recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-recipe) should be a synonym of [symfony-flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-flex).

Recipes are part of Symfony Flex. No need for a separate tag.

Comment: Good, but could we make [symfony-recipe] a synonym of [symfony-flex], in case of someone don't know and wanted to tag their question under symfony-recipe?

Comment: That's also fine!